# Ajax without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

As JavaScript can be disabled in the browser by the user, I wonder if there is any way of developing an Application which uses Ajax but it doesn't use Javascript, so even if Javascript is disabled it goes on working. 
Is there any limitation?

Comment: AJAX: Asynchronous **JavaScript** And XML.

Comment: I would say it very depends on what you want to achieve. Maybe you can achieve some things in other ways, but I don't know. Of course you cannot do an *XMLHttpRequest* without JS. Some people have a wrong understanding of what *Ajax* means.

Comment: I was going to recommend Google Gears but that too requires Javascript to be enabled.

Comment: as has been already said, AJAX by definition includes Javascript; but web apps themselves can easily be done without client-side scripting if you're comfortable with round-trips to the server for each operation: just use plain HTML forms and appropriate HTTP status codes (ie `204 No Content` allows to send a message to the server without reloading the page; sadly, `205 Reset Content` isn't widely supported)

Comment: You can simply use C# instead. You can use C# without .NET framework installed. Maybe you also can view the Page without a browser. Even without a computer.. If you only have a strong wish everything can be possible.. :)

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I supposed it was no possible but I wanted to know if there was something I was missing.

Comment: I saw today a paper in my university that said something like "you DON'T need JS to use AJAX, and some explanation I actually don't remember" but it may be something like what @Christoph said... Or possibly, although it is kinda 1.0, using iframes, which isn't properly ajax, but you could refresh the iframe content without refreshing the page

Comment: @Martin shouldn't it be called AJAJ - Asynchronous JavaScript and **JSON** (as it's mainly used with JSON)? Or maybe some other name more fitting to it's purpose of "get stuff from the server without reloading the entire page". Tech names are usually really a bad source of any meaning.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

AJAX isn't possible without Javascript, because it presupposes JS code running on the client. If JS is disabled, there's nothing that can execute in the browser and contact the server - only "dead" HTML and CSS.

Flash is an alternative, but then again it can be disabled too.

Comment: Flash is more prone to hacker attacks than Javascript, and once the hacker is in a lot more can be done with a Flash hack..

Answer (score 7):

The limitation is the 'j' in Ajax. You need JavaScript to do Ajax - there's no way to update page content without it.

You should always try to design your Ajax applications so that links have a non-ajax fallback wherever possible. So if you have a link which updates a div with new data, when JavaScript is turned off that link will lead to a new page which has that div updated.

Answer (score 7):

You should look into "graceful degradation". It won't give you the dynamic input/feedback that Ajax "gave the web", but that was how most of the web worked back in 2005 and before.

Other than that, your choices are Flash or Java but I wouldn't recommend that and I don't get the impression you were looking for such a recommendation either.

Comment: +1 for *graceful degradation*. Belonging to this: **unobtrusive JavaScript** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Answer (score 6):

[AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) actually means Asynchronous **Javascript** And Xml -- note the Javascript part.

You cannot use Ajax without Javascript : HTML by itself is not dynamic : you need Javascript for that.

*(Yeah "Ajax" means more than just AJAX -- but the idea is the same)*

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can't literally use Ajax without Javascript, since the "J" in Ajax is for "Javascript"

The best you can do is test for Javascript functionality and load a non-Ajax version of the page instead.

Answer (score 5):

Ajax = **A**synchronous **J**avaScript **A**nd **X**ML. You can't have Ajax without JavaScript!

Answer (score 4):

As others said, AJAX *is* JavaScript. But there are Alternatives (but each one requires plugins to be present)

- Silverlight (works as Moonlight on Linux too!)
- Flash
- Java

But be sure, if somebody deactivated JavaScript, he has these deactivated as well. I believe most people don't deactivate JavaScript because nowadays it is very safe and performant and doesn't annoy very much in contrast to other plugins.
Besides, most modern websites require JavaScript.

You can also use server sided scripting like PHP and then use HTTP-META-REFRESH to refresh your page, this can in some cases simulate cases where you would have used JavaScript otherwise.

But it greatly depends on what you are trying to do, it would be nice to hear that from you.

Answer (score 4):

Dude ! 
AJAX is Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no way, its same like running car without engine or gas ..

Comment: You can still get out and push it :)

Comment: @codymanix then its not a car, you can also send request to the server without javascript/ajax .. it also "works" but that is not asynchronous then.

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript bit in `Asynchronous JavaScript And XML` is rather important, as it is the Javascript that manipulates the page clientside, so even if you were able to do an asynchroneus post to the server and get a result back - it wouldn't be possible for you to update the page content.

Most people have Javascript enabled these days, and I don't know of many rich sites that don't rely on Javascript in some way. So unless its a clear demand from your client or such, I would not worry about browsers that disable Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

actually, not sure if this helps or not, if it's `sending` data that you need through GET, you can use a simple image, like:

```
<img src="/myfile.php?a=log&id=myuser&page=index.php" />
```

I would not go calling this an AJAX application though :D

Comment: You can use HTTP-META-REFRESH to refresh image for a slide-show