# Page refresh while login validation

Tags: php

In a PHP Code, when i am trying to validate basic login validation (empty field, numeric field, etc.), my page gets refresh and all the already entered data gets away. My sample code:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{

// username and password sent from form 
$MailId=$_POST['MailId']; 
$Password=$_POST['Password']; 


  if(empty($_POST['MailId'])) 
  {
    $MerrorMessage = "You forgot to enter a MailId!";
  }

  else if(!preg_match("/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/", $MailId))
  {
    $MailformaterrorMessage = "Email ID format is not correct!";
  }


  if(empty($_POST['Password'])) 
  {
    $PerrorMessage = "You forgot to enter a Password!";
  }


  else
    {
      main Logic
    .....

  }
```

Any suggestions if without using Javascript, page refresh can be avoided ?

Comment: Without `Javascript`, `Jquery` page refresh is inevitable

Comment: Put the data they did give you back into the form when you display it again

Comment: Haha it sounds like you already know the answer is javascript for the form verification and php for the form processing

Comment: :) but was seeking any chance if it can be done without Javascript ...

Comment: You either use javascript to prevent the reload or reload the form again with the error message and the supplied data pre-populated into the form they are your options.

Comment: Oh God....now have to learn Javascript and AJAX also ; even I am new to PHP also :'(

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX instead to validate it to the server without RELOADING. Read more about how AJAX works and its uses .

Comment: So you want an AJAX effect without the use of JAVASCRIPT? o.O

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386602/ajax-without-javascript

maybe it'll help

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, to validate data without refreshing pages. `JavaScript` & `AJAX`

I would prefer the latter, but here is how a simple Js validation would look like, just to get the picture.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var name = 'PHPNoob'; 

if(name.length < 2){
        document.write('Name can not be less than 2 characters long');
}else{
    document.write('Name is oK');
}
</script>
```

That for example, would validate if name is less than 2 character long or not.

If you want to validate using AJAX, you would have to create the same PHP page your have, and another AJAX file, to send those values to the server for validation. Since AJAX is very quick, and you may have lots of benefits using that instead of Js

Comment: Don't forget that you should still validate server side on submission even if the form has been "validated" client side before submission as it is trivial to bypass any form of client side or pre-submission validation

Comment: @Anigel yes. I meant that as well.