# Need to post form Asynchronously without using jquery in MVC4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working in MVC from last one year and in most of cases i am using JQuery ajax calling for Calling controller method. Now my requirement is that I have a button(Add User) on page on its click i open a Modal popup on which i need to partial view and 2 buttons(Save and Cancel).

After filling form i click on Save button .Now i want to MVC functionality and want to post data using Asynchronous Method of Ajax form. After save i want to reload Partial view with empty form.

Can someone guide me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't want to use jQuery for AJAX calls, you'll need to learn the [core AJAX API in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) and use it. Is there a reason you can't use jQuery? It just gives a nice wrapper around the core AJAX API, so you'd just be writing equivalent but more verbose/complex code yourself if you don't use jQuery or a similar library that wraps the the core AJAX API.

Answer (score 1):

Youre looking for a javascript only kind of call?

```
function submitForm()
{ 
var xhr; 
try {  xhr = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');   }
catch (e) 
{
    try {   xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');    }
    catch (e2) 
    {
      try {  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();     }
      catch (e3) {  xhr = false;   }
    }
 }

xhr.onreadystatechange  = function()
{ 
     if(xhr.readyState  == 4)
     {
          if(xhr.status  == 200) 
              document.ajax.dyn="Received:"  + xhr.responseText; 
          else
             document.ajax.dyn="Error code " + xhr.status;
     }
}; 

xhr.open(GET, "data.txt",  true); 
xhr.send(null); 
}
```

and your HTML:

```
<FORM method="POST" name="ajax" action="controller/action">                  
     <INPUT type="BUTTON" value="Submit"  ONCLICK="submitForm()">
     <INPUT type="text" name="dyn"  value=""> 
</FORM>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply . But i want to use MVC ajax form to post it Async. Don't want to use any JQuery or javascript.

Comment: Ok sorry, I'm not sure how to do that, or even what you mean :/ - just out of interest what is the situation you why you cannot use js/jquery?

Comment: @user1770461 AJAX means "Asynchronous JavaScript + XML". You [can't use AJAX without JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386602/ajax-without-javascript) by definition. As the linked question indicates, you could use a technology like Flash for a similar functionality, but that's not the right tool for this job. You could also refresh the entire page, but that's no longer asynchronous.